How to label empty images in AzureML Data Labeling Project?
I want to start labeling data in AzureML. However some of my training-data images do not contain any objects and would thus not be labeled.
I don't want to skip those images but instead want them to be essentially a null-tensor for training purposes.
-Tried adding a background-label and labeling everything except the object with it. This is too much additional work and makes labeling the object over the existing opaque background-mask more difficult

you can create a label called none and give that empty image this none as label. draw the polygon on whole image since it is empty.

How will this work when the masks get exported? If I export a regular image with an object I get one pixel-mask with the label-name and one called "null.png". Will this give me another mask with the name "none.png" or will this be converted to "null.png"?

You will get as per the label. none.png and null.png

If I did that I'd have to label everything that isn't an object this way on images with objects. This is exactly what I don't want to have to do.

You are asking how to handle empty images without labeling them right?

Yes. I want to essentially know how to label an entire image as empty, so that it gets saved as a null-tensor.

You can do skip on the empty image which is not required.

If I skip the image, the image will not have a corresponding mask when exporting the labels. It would just delete information.

Then you need to manually label all the images to any label as i said None.

Yes but I was asking if there is a way to avoid this because this would mean that I'd have to label any background in any image as that None-label.

If you want this empty image as information or data you have to label it to something and that is manually no way to do it automatically. Also for every image there is another image exported as null.png which is opposite to the polygon you have draw
